# copy contents of a list to a Dictionary<int, string>

Tags: c#-4.0

I am pretty new to C# and stuck with a problem with collections. I have a dictionaty with some values say: [(5, "abc"), (6, "def")]. I call a method and get a List like: {"mno", "pqr"}. Now I want to update the value of the dictionary with contents of the list. The problem is the key of the map may start from any number, say from 5. But the starting index of the new list will always be 0 as usual, the length of both the list and the map being same...so I can't so: map[i] = list[i], because they won't match. Can someone please tell me how to replace the contents of the dictionary with that of the list? Please please!!!

Comment: are you trying to empty the dictionary and update it with the new elements in the list?

Comment: yes kind of, I mean the index(keys) will remain the same, only the values will update

Comment: So the list will have the same number of elements as the dictionary?

Comment: Where are these keys coming from?

Comment: yes, no. of elements are same

Comment: the dictionary actulally holds the IDs of a database table which are the primary keys of that table, serving as Keys of dictioanry, and another field(string) from that table...so I would need those IDs later to update that table with the contents of the list

Comment: The idea behind a dictionary is to provide a mapping between a simple value (key) to another value (value). Assuming you have an object which represents your data (model) where it contains properties for the Id as well as the value you should just keep using a list, then use linq to query against it. There is little performance difference between the two.

Comment: In your example, do you care whether you get `5=>mno, 6=>pqr` or `5=>pqr, 6=>mno`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple For Loop

```
for (int index = 0; index < map.Count; index++)
{
    map[map.ElementAt(index).Key] = list[index];
}
```

Using Linq

```
var result  = map.Zip(list, (m, l) => new { Key = m.Key, Value = l })
                 .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

Comment: Damith that was fast!!..thanks a ton :)..would you mind explaining a bit?

Comment: I think you can understand `for` loop, Linq Zip can be use to do something with corresponding elements of two sequences.

Comment: This works only if you don't care what order the list gets assigned to the map's keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using LINQ that will create a new `Dictionary` with the same keys as the old dictionary, but values coming from the list:

```
     map = map.Keys
              .OrderBy(k => k)
              .Zip(list, (k, v) => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(k, v))
              .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

If you need to update the original `Dictionary` instead of creating a new one, this will do it:

```
foreach (var kvp in map.Keys
                       .OrderBy(k => k)
                       .Zip(list, (k, v) => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(k, v)))
    map[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
```